# How do i edit django-machina forum template and styling

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am using **django-machina** for forum in my app. I want to change the template and also style on my own. I did that by copying all the templates of its to my template directory and copied style(machina.board_theme.min.css) to my static folder. Is this a best way if i want to edit the style and template? Also if i want to upload image for my profile, the profile gets updated but image is not shown({{ profile.avatar.url }}).

**Configuration**

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"staticcollection")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR, )
```

**my template structure**

[image]

Please advise me the best way to override my template styling. I could not understand from the documentation part.

Comment: The image is shown by serving media file in urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

In the static folder of your project there is a css file. Just change it (although it's min, so its hard to find what you're looking for).

PS: I tried, but nothing was happening. So go to the installation folder of machina, 
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\machina\static\machina\build\css

Comment: This works for me.  Move the CSS file to your own project's `static/css`, and also modify the `board_base.html` template file to point to the new CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To override the _base template and board_base.html, just create a "templates" folder in your project root directory and move a copy of the HTML files to this directory and customize from there.

Avoid setting "MACHINA_FORUM_NAME" or "MACHINA_BASE_TEMPLATE_NAME" in your **settings.py**, this setting was one of the reasons for my confusion.